# Javascript - File upload; check if image has transparent background

Tags: javascript

I want to check the image transparency and display an error message if the image background is not transparent. I have the `function hasAlpha(file)` to check it the file has a transparent background but I am not sure how to pass it through the `function uploadFile(file)` function which already checks for file size.

I think I can duplicate the file size `if` statement inside of `if (xhr.upload) {}` and check if the uploaded image is transparent but I am not sure how to incorporate the `function hasAlpha(file)` with the rest of the code.

```js
// File Upload
//
function ekUpload() {
  function Init() {
    console.log("Upload Initialised");

    var fileSelect = document.getElementById("file-upload"),
      fileDrag = document.getElementById("file-drag"),
      submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");

    fileSelect.addEventListener("change", fileSelectHandler, false);

    // Is XHR2 available?
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload) {
      // File Drop
      fileDrag.addEventListener("dragover", fileDragHover, false);
      fileDrag.addEventListener("dragleave", fileDragHover, false);
      fileDrag.addEventListener("drop", fileSelectHandler, false);
    }
  }

  function fileDragHover(e) {
    var fileDrag = document.getElementById("file-drag");

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    fileDrag.className =
      e.type === "dragover" ? "hover" : "modal-body file-upload";
  }

  function fileSelectHandler(e) {
    // Fetch FileList object
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // Cancel event and hover styling
    fileDragHover(e);

    // Process all File objects
    for (var i = 0, f;
      (f = files[i]); i++) {
      parseFile(f);
      uploadFile(f);
    }
  }

  // Output
  function output(msg) {
    // Response
    var m = document.getElementById("messages");
    m.innerHTML = msg;
  }

  function hasAlpha(file) {
    var canvas = file.getElementById("file-image");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var data = file.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data,
      hasAlphaPixels = false;
    for (var i = 3, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
      if (data[i] < 255) {
        hasAlphaPixels = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return hasAlphaPixels;
  }

  function parseFile(file) {
    console.log(file.name);
    output("<strong>" + encodeURI(file.name) + "</strong>");

    // var fileType = file.type;
    // console.log(fileType);
    var imageName = file.name;

    var isGood = /\.(?=svg|jpg|png|jpeg)/gi.test(imageName);
    if (isGood) {
      document.getElementById("start").classList.add("hidden");
      document.getElementById("response").classList.remove("hidden");
      document.getElementById("notimage").classList.add("hidden");
      // Thumbnail Preview
      document.getElementById("file-image").classList.remove("hidden");
      document.getElementById("file-image").src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("file-image").classList.add("hidden");
      document.getElementById("notimage").classList.remove("hidden");
      document.getElementById("start").classList.remove("hidden");
      document.getElementById("response").classList.add("hidden");
      document.getElementById("file-upload-form").reset();
    }
  }

  function uploadFile(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      fileInput = document.getElementById("class-roster-file"),
      fileSizeLimit = 1024; // In MB

    if (xhr.upload) {
      // Check if file is less than x MB
      if (file.size <= fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
        // File received / failed
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // Everything is good!
            // document.location.reload(true);
          }
        };

        // Start upload
        xhr.open(
          "POST",
          document.getElementById("file-upload-form").action,
          true
        );
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        xhr.send(file);
      } else {
        output("Please upload a smaller file (< " + fileSizeLimit + " MB).");
      }
    }
  }

  // Check for the various File API support.
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    Init();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("file-drag").style.display = "none";
  }
}
ekUpload();
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 90px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.uploader input[type="file"],
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Upload  -->
<form id="file-upload-form" class="uploader">
  <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
  <label for="file-upload" id="file-drag">
    <img id="file-image" src="#" alt="Preview" class="hidden">
    <div id="start">
      <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
      <div id="notimage" class="hidden">Please select an image</div>
    </div>
    <div id="response" class="hidden">
      <div id="messages"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
</form>
<div class="error hidden">Your logo must have a transparent background. Please set RBGa
```

Comment: Why dont you set it as a requestheader or querystring?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Would you be able to demonstrate in a snippet?

Comment: You should know that if you understand the code you posted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I modified / fixed your `hasAlpha()` function. It returns a promise which resolves on image load event or rejects on image error event. I aslo added hidden `<canvas>` element, which is used by this function. I added transparency check into `fileSelectHandler()` function, move it to another place if needed.

Code:

```js
// File Upload
//
function ekUpload() {
  function Init() {
    console.log("Upload Initialised");

    var fileSelect = document.getElementById("file-upload"),
      fileDrag = document.getElementById("file-drag"),
      submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");

    fileSelect.addEventListener("change", fileSelectHandler, false);

    // Is XHR2 available?
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload) {
      // File Drop
      fileDrag.addEventListener("dragover", fileDragHover, false);
      fileDrag.addEventListener("dragleave", fileDragHover, false);
      fileDrag.addEventListener("drop", fileSelectHandler, false);
    }
  }

  function fileDragHover(e) {
    var fileDrag = document.getElementById("file-drag");

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    fileDrag.className =
      e.type === "dragover" ? "hover" : "modal-body file-upload";
  }

  async function fileSelectHandler(e) {
    // Fetch FileList object
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // Cancel event and hover styling
    fileDragHover(e);

    // Process all File objects
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const f = files[i];
      if (await hasAlpha(f)) {
        console.log('Selected image is transparent');
        parseFile(f);
        uploadFile(f);
      }
      else {
        console.log('Selected image is not transparent');
        document.querySelector('#response').classList.remove('hidden');
        document.querySelector('#file-image').classList.add('hidden');
        output('<strong class="warning">Image background is not transparent</strong>');
      }
    }
  }

  // Output
  function output(msg) {
    // Response
    var m = document.getElementById("messages");
    m.innerHTML = msg;
  }

  function hasAlpha(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let hasAlpha = false;
      const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
      const img = new Image();
      img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
      img.onerror = reject;
      img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
      
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
      
        for (let j = 0; j < imgData.length; j += 4) {
          if (imgData[j + 3] < 255) {
            hasAlpha = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        resolve(hasAlpha);
      };
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    });
  }

  function parseFile(file) {
    console.log(file.name);
    output("<strong>" + encodeURI(file.name) + "</strong>");

    // var fileType = file.type;
    // console.log(fileType);
    var imageName = file.name;

    var isGood = /\.(?=svg|jpg|png|jpeg)/gi.test(imageName);
    if (isGood) {
      document.getElementById("start").classList.add("hidden");
      document.getElementById("response").classList.remove("hidden");
      document.getElementById("notimage").classList.add("hidden");
      // Thumbnail Preview
      document.getElementById("file-image").classList.remove("hidden");
      document.getElementById("file-image").src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("file-image").classList.add("hidden");
      document.getElementById("notimage").classList.remove("hidden");
      document.getElementById("start").classList.remove("hidden");
      document.getElementById("response").classList.add("hidden");
      document.getElementById("file-upload-form").reset();
    }
  }

  function uploadFile(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      fileInput = document.getElementById("class-roster-file"),
      fileSizeLimit = 1024; // In MB

    if (xhr.upload) {
      // Check if file is less than x MB
      if (file.size <= fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
        // File received / failed
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // Everything is good!
            // document.location.reload(true);
          }
        };

        // Start upload
        xhr.open(
          "POST",
          document.getElementById("file-upload-form").action,
          true
        );
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        xhr.send(file);
      } else {
        output("Please upload a smaller file (< " + fileSizeLimit + " MB).");
      }
    }
  }

  // Check for the various File API support.
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    Init();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("file-drag").style.display = "none";
  }
}
ekUpload();
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 90px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.uploader input[type="file"],
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.warning {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2000px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Upload  -->
<form id="file-upload-form" class="uploader">
  <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />
  <label for="file-upload" id="file-drag">
    <img id="file-image" src="#" alt="Preview" class="hidden">
    <div id="start">
      <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
      <div id="notimage" class="hidden">Please select an image</div>
    </div>
    <div id="response" class="hidden">
      <div id="messages"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
</form>
<div class="error hidden">Your logo must have a transparent background. Please set RBGa</div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Does `canvas` allow for SVG? I receive the following error 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."

Comment: as mentioned at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image, adding `img..crossOrigin = "Anonymous"` should solve mentioned by you problem. I fixed it from lowercase 'anonymous' to upper case. Please check now my snippet

Comment: It doesn't seem to accept svg. I created a codepen here for reference: https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/RwNVvXV

Comment: I tested your codepen code with SVG file and it seems to work, it also logged in console that uploaded SVG file is transparent. Please attach your SVG file (if possible) and I will check it

Comment: I have a couple of questions about this script, (1) when an image is dragged onto the form how does it save the file because $_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]; seems to be empty for files that were dragged onto the form. If youclick the upload button $_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]; shows the file. (2) where does this script save the files?

Comment: Currently the dragged file is not saved anywhere, I only answered the part of alpha transparency checking. The function which is responsible for upload here is `uploadFile(f)`, which just executes an XHR POST to form's `action` attribute. In the given example this attribute is absent, so the POST will go to its default - current location. I did not deal with this part of the code, but you can add an `action` attribute to the form and check it. Thanks for your questions!